# Removing unnecessary vertical scrollbar in <select> in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using  with only two options in it and it is showing vertical scrollbar.How can I remove it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUwF6.png)

```
<select style="overflow-y:hidden">
 <option>name</option>
 <option>age</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you give it some space from the bottom, lets say some more height or padding in the select menu?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem ? Because for me there is no vertical scrollbar even with two options.

Comment: Do you see a scrollbar in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fxwxtuux/) example?

Comment: I am using this in angular js and it is showing unnecessary scrollbar.

Comment: Tried giving css but it is not helping.

Comment: can you take screenshot of the output because it seems no vertical scrollbar even with two options.

Comment: I have provided the sreenshot above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your browser zoom, it happens when your browser zoom is not correct

[image: Could be because of wrong browser zoom]

Comment: Changed my browser's zoom to 100 per cent.Now it is not showing any scrollbar.It's perfect.Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help, You are most welcome :)